# Use paragraph-separated list to remove songs from iTunes playlist

Tags: applescript, itunes

I can get songs from a playlist based on a text file with a different title in each paragraph, but can I use another text file to delete any songs in playlist 'SongList' whose title matches one of the titles in my 'SongList' text file?

Know how to read the text file

```
set mySampleText to read file "Macintosh SSD:path:to:file.txt"
```

And how to get paras of it

```
set paras to paragraphs of mySampleText
```

But I can't find a way to delete any tracks who share a name with any line of mySampleText.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Tardy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below find tracks with same title as in your text file and delete.
Be careful, there is no reverse to the delete action !!!

```
set FText to choose file "select your text file" -- select text file

set mySampleText to read FText  -- read txt file
set Paras to paragraphs of mySampleText

tell application "iTunes"
tell playlist "My preferred playlist"
repeat with aSong in Paras -- loop to each title
    set myTracks to (every track whose name is aSong)
    if (count of myTracks) > 0 then -- only if found
        set myTrack to item 1 of myTracks -- take first item found
        Delete myTrack
    end if
end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

You may have to manage the case when you have multiple tracks with the same title. Script above only takes the 1st track found.

I strongly reccomand that you replace the "delete" by "play" during debuting !! (to be safe).

Last, but not least, make sure your txt file is properly encoded if you have special characters in your titles.

Comment: Pbell, does it just delete them from the playlist? I don't want to delete them from iTunes entirely.

Comment: I have updated the script adding "tell playlist" ... and "end tell". Doing so, the track is only deleted from your specified playlist. Without this block, the track is deleted from the main library (and then from all playlists).

Comment: That is really helpful. Thanks, pbell! I forgot you could 'tell' the playlist too!